# Export a function: can't find variable

Tags: function, react-native, import, export

I try to create a function and export it to be called in differents components but i don't know very well how it work and an error occur when I do this:

function code:

```
export function myFunction( param ) {
   //my code...
   var ret = param
   return ret;
};
```

Call in the component:

```
import {components} from 'react'
import {myFunction} from './class.js';
import {Alert} from 'react-native';

class myClass extends Component{
  componentDidMount() {
    var val = myFunction('the param');
    Alert.alert(val);
  }
}
```

And occur this error:

Can't find variable: myFunction

Thanks for help.

Comment: is class.js in the same directory?

Comment: yes certainly, it is.

Comment: Try this `import myFunction from './class.js';`

Comment: the error always occur...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing it wrong. Here is the right way to do it. Use       `const` instead of `function`. And also, you can always use arrow function as below:

```
export const myFunction = ( param ) => {
  //my code...
  var ret = param
  return ret;
};
```

Now you can import `myFunction` as you did above. Hope it helps.

Comment: It help me now i have another error:
undefined is not a function

Comment: In the first line of your second block of code, why are you using 
`import {components} from 'react';` ? 

You should probably try using this: 
`import React, { Component } from 'react';`

Comment: This is no different from export function myFunction. Both work in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

`export default function myFunction( param ) {
       //my code... 
       var ret = param return ret; 
};`

Try it and let me know its helpful.